# Filtro en android studio

Tags: android

tengo una duda, en una app consulto una bbdd sql server para mostrar los datos en un gridview con el siguiente codigo:

```
@Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            List<Map<String, String>> data1 = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();
            try {
                connect = concClass();
                if (connect != null) {
                    String query = "SELECT * FROM Pedidos";
                    Statement st = connect.createStatement();
                    ResultSet resultSet = st.executeQuery(query);


                    while (resultSet.next()) {

                        Map<String, String> tab = new HashMap<String, String>();

                        tab.put("Cliente", resultSet.getString("Cliente"));
                        tab.put("Clase", resultSet.getString("Clase"));
                        tab.put("Producto", resultSet.getString("Producto"));
                        tab.put("Cantidad", resultSet.getString("Cantidad"));
                        tab.put("Formato", resultSet.getString("Formato"));
                        tab.put("Piezas", resultSet.getString("Piezas"));
                        tab.put("Hora", resultSet.getString("Hora"));
                        data1.add(tab);

                        String[] from = {"Cliente", "Clase","Producto","Cantidad","Formato","Piezas","Hora"};
                        int[] to = {R.id.txtcliente, R.id.txtclase,R.id.txtproducto,R.id.txtcantidad,R.id.txtformato,R.id.txtpiezas,R.id.txthora};
                        adapter = new SimpleAdapter(ListadoPedidos.this, data1, R.layout.listlayoutemplate, from, to);
                        list.setAdapter(adapter);
```

todo funciona correcto, me muestra todos los datos que hay en la bbdd, menos una columna de fecha que no quiero la muestre, ahora bien, esos datos los quiero filtrar por fecha, y uso este codigo para ello en lugar de solo "SELECT * FROM Pedidos"

```
String query = "SELECT * FROM Pedidos WHERE Fecha >= '"+startDate+"' 
AND Fecha <= '"+endDate+"'"; Statement st = connect.createStatement(); 

ResultSet resultSet = st.executeQuery(query);
```

y asi no me funciona... alguien puede hecharme un cable? saludos

```
String query = "SELECT * FROM Pedidos WHERE Fecha >= '"+startDate+"' 
AND Fecha <= '"+endDate+"'"; Statement st = connect.createStatement();

ResultSet resultSet = st.executeQuery(query);
```

Comment: ¿Qué hay exactamente en `startDate` y en `endDate`? ¿Has probado la consulta directamente en la base de datos con esos valores y arroja datos? Pulsa en [edit] y completa tu pregunta.

Comment: en startdate y enddate hay un edittext en cada uno. no arroja nada.

Comment: Pon un ejemplo de cómo se muestran los valores que recoges en ambas variables.

Comment: EditText startDate = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.startDate);

Comment: Me refiero a los valores en sí mismos, pues si no están en el formato adecuado no habrá resultados. Son cosas básicas de depuración que debiste haber ya verificado.

Comment: son fechas, aunque he probado por ejemplo a en vez de buscar por fecha, buscar por clientes (solo texto) y me pasa igual, no muestra nada

Comment: por supuesto cambiando la columna de búsqueda por su nombre correspondiente (clientes) y solo un campo de busqueda y no dos como en las fechas

Comment: ¿Y buscando directamente en la base de datos sí funciona? ¿Cómo es la instrucción SQL que se produce en tu código?

Comment: String query = "SELECT * FROM Pedidos" asi si funciona, y me muestra todos los registos.

Comment: String query = "SELECT * FROM Pedidos WHERE Fecha >= '"+startDate+"' AND Fecha <= '"+endDate+"'"; Statement st = connect.createStatement(); ResultSet resultSet = st.executeQuery(query); asi no funciona

Comment: A ver, muestra la consulta real que se produce. Se trata de **depurar** el código,.verificando lo que se produce en la realidad, con los datos en sí mismos.

Comment: @OrionD solo debes verificar cual es el formato con el que guardas la fecha en tu tabla y revisa como se esta agregando a las variables startDate y endDate

Comment: Gracias por las contestaciones, como ya dije probe tambien como texto y no era por el formato, aqui dejo solucion por si alguien le puede ayudar. En las variables +endDate y startDate debe ir asi:  String query = "SELECT * FROM Pedidos WHERE Fecha >= '"+startDate.getText().toString()+"' AND Fecha <= '"+endDate.getText().toString()+"'";